# How to avoid two finger scroll in iphone?

Tags: iphone, css, scroll

I have vertical scroll bar inside of my web page. When i run this web site in iphone, I have to use two finger to scroll the content. Is there any way to fix this problem? The content needs to be scroll by using single finger.

I have a code like this

```
<div style="height:600px; overflow:scroll">
Content goes here
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a problem; it's just the way it's supposed to work.

Comment: @Boltclock: But how users know there are more content? They might miss the content. So i need to show the vertical scroll bar at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scrolling library like [TouchScroll](https://github.com/davidaurelio/TouchScroll) or [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll). iScroll has more features, but having tried both in a production application, I found TouchScroll performed more reliably.